# Google Mock Leaking on EXPECT_CALL even with virtual destructor

Tags: c++, memory, googletest, googlemock

I am getting a memory leak on this test below which appears to be triggered by EXPECT_CALL since removing this line --

```
EXPECT_CALL(*AMock_, method(_,_);
```

makes the leak go away.

Here is the test:

```
TEST_F(Test, testing)
{
    auto AMock_ = std::make_unique<AMock>();

    EXPECT_CALL(*AMock_, method(_,_).Times(AtLeast(1));
    AMock_->init(NUMROW, NUMCOL);

    EXPECT_TRUE(Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(AMock_.get()));
}
```

Here is the mock:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include "BaseB.h"

class AMock: public BaseB
{
public:
MOCK_METHOD2(method, void(int row, int col));
};
```

And BaseB class:

```
class BaseB: public BaseA
{
public:
    BaseB();
    virtual ~BaseB();
    virtual void init(int row, int col);
};

void BaseB::init(int row, int col)
{
   int x = row / 2;
   int y = col / 5;
   method(x, y);
   //codes codes codes..
}
```

Which was derived from BaseA:

```
class BaseA
{
public:
    BaseA();
    virtual ~BaseA();

    virtual void method(int param1, int param2);
};
```

The mock's base classes (BaseB and BaseA) both have virtual destructors already so I am not sure what is wrong. Help!

Comment: Did you actually define the destructor for BaseA and BaseB?  (Note that BaseB has a virtual destructor even if you don't declare it as such because BaseA has a virtual destructor.)

Comment: Have now updated it to ```virtual ~BaseA(){};```.. Same behavior -- leak is still there :(

Comment: I can't reproduce the memory leak with the given code. Can you update your question and provide the fixture class?